# Simulate application on an iPad mini w/ Flashbuilder

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air, adobe, flash-builder

I'm almost ready to launch my app on the store. But i found some issues with the display of components on an iPad Mini. It all works on a regular ipad and a ipad retina.

Simple question, is there any way to simulate the app on an iPad Mini (or more devices from Apple) with FlashBuilder?

Info app:
- Flex mobile project
- made in FlashBuilder

Comment: Why not to add a new "device simulator" with a screen resolution / DPi same as iPad mini.

Comment: Not the correct display, it's way to big to simulate the correct ipad mini display.

Comment: You need to take in consideration the DPI as well...

Comment: Same problem, tried it before.

Comment: The iPad 1, 2, and Mini all have the same resolution display. Only difference is the Mini is 162 DPI and the iPad 1/2 is 132 DPI. That DPI difference isn't significant and, if you are using Flex, they both use the 160 applicationDPI setting regardless. Without seeing exactly what the "issues with the display of components" is, I don't think we can help.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to download Xcode and use it's simulator. It is much more like the actual device than Air simulation. This became available in FlashBuilder 4.7 from the Run Configurations. I believe it may have been available in FB 4.6 from adl as well.

Comment: Driezzz: did that answer your question? If so, and you can vote my answer up, much appreciated.